# Convert a SQL query to an HTML table for email

Tags: html, plsql

I need some help this problem. I want sql queries to html tables for email but ı dont know how to convert

this is sql queries

EXPLAIN PLAN FOR

```
  select disk_reads, sql_id, DIRECT_WRITES, BUFFER_GETS, USER_IO_WAIT_TIME, CPU_TIME, FETCHES from (select *
  from v$sql
  order by disk_reads DESC ) where rownum<=10


  select * from table(dbms_xplan.display_awr('sql_id'));
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Do you want to read data from a Database and include this data in an HTML email?

Comment: ı want to put the data received from the query into the html email

Answer (score 1):

It's worth giving the venerable `OWA` framework a try.

```
create or replace procedure htmldemo(p_sql in varchar2) is
  page HTP.htbuf_arr;
  version INTEGER; 
  cgiNames OWA.vc_arr;
  cgiValues OWA.vc_arr;
  lines NUMBER := 99999999999;
begin
  version := OWA.initialize;
  OWA.init_cgi_env (0, cgiNames, cgiValues);
  owa_util.cellsprint(p_sql);  
  OWA.get_page (thepage => page, irows => lines);
  FOR i IN 1 .. lines LOOP
    dbms_output.put_line(page (i));
  END LOOP;
end;
/
```

Demonstration:

```
begin
  htmldemo('select e.ename, e.job, d.dname from emp e join dept d on d.deptno = e.deptno and rownum <= 3');
end;
/
```

Output:

```
<TR>
<TD>KING</TD>
<TD>PRESIDENT</TD>
<TD>ACCOUNTING</TD>
</TR>
<TR>
<TD>BLAKE</TD>
<TD>MANAGER</TD>
<TD>SALES</TD>
</TR>
<TR>
<TD>CLARK</TD>
<TD>MANAGER</TD>
<TD>ACCOUNTING</TD>
</TR>
```

This demo gets the HTML for whatever you generate in an array, and you can take it from there.
Note also that this just generates the table rows. You can use other `OWA` features to build the rest of the page or you can build it yourself.

I wouldn't rely on this for a critical system, but for occasional status emails, it might work.